# Prevent iOS keyboard from disappearing / reappearing between UITextFields?

Tags: ios, objective-c, forms, uitextfield

I've got a form with some `UITextField` instances, and I've set up an accessory view to flip back and forth between them as you fill in the form. The ugliness is that the keyboard slides away, then immediately slides back for the next form.

Since it's going to remain there, is there a way to get it to simply stay up throughout the whole form, rather than this ugly/silly gone/back behaviour? I may be doing something wrong programmatically, I'm telling fields to `resignFirstResponder` before the new one does `becomeFirstResponder` – is that the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to called `resignFirstResponder` when switching between text fields, iOS will handle this for you when calling `becomeFirstResponder` on another object. You just need to call `resignFirstResponder` if/when you want to hide the keyboard, say at the end of the form.

Comment: So how do I give the next text field a focus, if not by calling `becomeFirstResponder` on it?

Comment: If the user taps on the next text field you do nothing, if you need to manually change "focus" to a different text field simply call `becomeFirstResponder` on it (without calling `resignFirstResponder` on the "current" text field).

Comment: I've updated my answer as I realised it didn't actually make much sense :p

Comment: It made plenty, and you've just saved me a headache. Thank you kindly, Sir!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is the cause. You can just call `becomeFirstResponder` without calling `resignFirstResponder` and you'll get what you want

Answer (score 2):

When you select other `UITextField` than automatically the last `UITextField` resign first responder so you should not `resignFirstResponder` every time. Just resign when you done with `UITextField` or user click on the `UIView`.